# how to jsonify an array containing objects with custom jsonification

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, express

So I have a CustomObject and an array containing a number of them.

Right now, when I say res.json(myArray), I get a standard jsonification of my CustomObject, i.e. field1:value, field2:value, ....

What I can not figure out is how to make a custom jsonification of my CustomObject, such as I only want to return a subset of the parameters.

What functions do I have to customize? In CustomObject only?

Comment: What is `res.json`? If you are in a node.js environment, you might want to tag your question with [tag:nodejs]

Comment: this is express. response giving a JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What functions do I have to customize? In CustomObject only?

Give your objects a `toJSON` method that returns an object with only the expected properties and it will be [recognized by `JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior).